# CNN in Julia gives error: LoadError: CUDNNError: CUDNN_STATUS_NOT_SUPPORTED (code 9)

Tags: julia, conv-neural-network, flux, cudnn

My goal is to run a 1D Convolutional Neural Network in Julia on the NVIDIA GPU, with Flux and CUDA. I managed to make a model and train it on the CPU but it will not work on the GPU. Have a look at the working example:

```
import Pkg
Pkg.activate("env")

using CUDA
using Random
using Flux

# Show info about CUDA
CUDA.versioninfo()
CUDA.device()

# Make training data and labels
train = rand(Float32, 720, 1, 100000)
labels = rand(Bool, 100000)
hot_labels = Flux.onehotbatch(labels, 0:1)

# Make the 1D CNN model
model = Chain(
    Conv((16,), 1=>16, relu, stride = 1, pad = 0,),
    MaxPool((2,)),

    Conv((8,), 16=>32, relu, stride = 1, pad = 0,),
    MaxPool((2,)),

    Flux.flatten,
    Dense(5504=>512, relu),
    Dropout(0.4),

    Dense(512=>256, relu),
    Dropout(0.4),
    Dense(256=>2, relu),
    softmax
)

optimizer = Flux.setup(Adam(), model)

# Copy the model and data to GPU
gpu_model = gpu(model)
gpu_train = gpu(train)

println("Try to use the cpu model with cpu data")
output = model(train)
println("Success")

println("Try to use the gpu model with gpu data")
gpu_output = gpu_model(gpu_train)
println("Success")

exit(0)
```

The output is this:

```
CUDA runtime 12.1, artifact installation
CUDA driver 12.1
NVIDIA driver 530.30.2

CUDA libraries: 
- CUBLAS: 12.1.3
- CURAND: 10.3.2
- CUFFT: 11.0.2
- CUSOLVER: 11.4.5
- CUSPARSE: 12.1.0
- CUPTI: 18.0.0
- NVML: 12.0.0+530.30.2

Julia packages: 
- CUDA.jl: 4.3.2
- CUDA_Driver_jll: 0.5.0+1
- CUDA_Runtime_jll: 0.6.0+0
- CUDA_Runtime_Discovery: 0.2.2

Toolchain:
- Julia: 1.9.1
- LLVM: 14.0.6
- PTX ISA support: 3.2, 4.0, 4.1, 4.2, 4.3, 5.0, 6.0, 6.1, 6.3, 6.4, 6.5, 7.0, 7.1, 7.2, 7.3, 7.4, 7.5
- Device capability support: sm_37, sm_50, sm_52, sm_53, sm_60, sm_61, sm_62, sm_70, sm_72, sm_75, sm_80, sm_86

2 devices:
  0: NVIDIA RTX A6000 (sm_86, 47.533 GiB / 47.988 GiB available)
  1: NVIDIA RTX A6000 (sm_86, 47.533 GiB / 47.988 GiB available)
Try to use the cpu model with cpu data
Success
Try to use the gpu model with gpu data
ERROR: LoadError: CUDNNError: CUDNN_STATUS_NOT_SUPPORTED (code 9)
Stacktrace:
  [1] throw_api_error(res::cuDNN.cudnnStatus_t)
    @ cuDNN ~/.julia/packages/cuDNN/3J08S/src/libcudnn.jl:11
  [2] check
    @ ~/.julia/packages/cuDNN/3J08S/src/libcudnn.jl:21 [inlined]
  [3] cudnnPoolingForward
    @ ~/.julia/packages/CUDA/pCcGc/lib/utils/call.jl:26 [inlined]
  [4] #cudnnPoolingForwardAD#679
    @ ~/.julia/packages/cuDNN/3J08S/src/pooling.jl:90 [inlined]
  [5] cudnnPoolingForwardAD
    @ ~/.julia/packages/cuDNN/3J08S/src/pooling.jl:89 [inlined]
  [6] #cudnnPoolingForwardWithDefaults#678
    @ ~/.julia/packages/cuDNN/3J08S/src/pooling.jl:57 [inlined]
  [7] #cudnnPoolingForward!#677
    @ ~/.julia/packages/cuDNN/3J08S/src/pooling.jl:36 [inlined]
  [8] cudnnPoolingForward!
    @ ~/.julia/packages/cuDNN/3J08S/src/pooling.jl:36 [inlined]
  [9] maxpool!(y::CuArray{Float32, 4, CUDA.Mem.DeviceBuffer}, x::CuArray{Float32, 4, CUDA.Mem.DeviceBuffer}, pdims::PoolDims{2, 2, 2, 4, 2})
    @ NNlibCUDA ~/.julia/packages/NNlibCUDA/C6t0p/src/cudnn/pooling.jl:16
 [10] maxpool!
    @ ~/.julia/packages/NNlibCUDA/C6t0p/src/cudnn/pooling.jl:54 [inlined]
 [11] maxpool(x::CuArray{Float32, 3, CUDA.Mem.DeviceBuffer}, pdims::PoolDims{1, 1, 1, 2, 1}; kwargs::Base.Pairs{Symbol, Union{}, Tuple{}, NamedTuple{(), Tuple{}}})
    @ NNlib ~/.julia/packages/NNlib/Fg3DQ/src/pooling.jl:119
 [12] maxpool
    @ ~/.julia/packages/NNlib/Fg3DQ/src/pooling.jl:114 [inlined]
 [13] MaxPool
    @ ~/.julia/packages/Flux/n3cOc/src/layers/conv.jl:697 [inlined]
 [14] macro expansion
    @ ~/.julia/packages/Flux/n3cOc/src/layers/basic.jl:53 [inlined]
 [15] _applychain(layers::Tuple{Conv{1, 2, typeof(relu), CuArray{Float32, 3, CUDA.Mem.DeviceBuffer}, CuArray{Float32, 1, CUDA.Mem.DeviceBuffer}}, MaxPool{1, 2}, Conv{1, 2, typeof(relu), CuArray{Float32, 3, CUDA.Mem.DeviceBuffer}, CuArray{Float32, 1, CUDA.Mem.DeviceBuffer}}, MaxPool{1, 2}, typeof(Flux.flatten), Dense{typeof(relu), CuArray{Float32, 2, CUDA.Mem.DeviceBuffer}, CuArray{Float32, 1, CUDA.Mem.DeviceBuffer}}, Dropout{Float64, Colon, CUDA.RNG}, Dense{typeof(relu), CuArray{Float32, 2, CUDA.Mem.DeviceBuffer}, CuArray{Float32, 1, CUDA.Mem.DeviceBuffer}}, Dropout{Float64, Colon, CUDA.RNG}, Dense{typeof(relu), CuArray{Float32, 2, CUDA.Mem.DeviceBuffer}, CuArray{Float32, 1, CUDA.Mem.DeviceBuffer}}, typeof(softmax)}, x::CuArray{Float32, 3, CUDA.Mem.DeviceBuffer})
    @ Flux ~/.julia/packages/Flux/n3cOc/src/layers/basic.jl:53
 [16] (::Chain{Tuple{Conv{1, 2, typeof(relu), CuArray{Float32, 3, CUDA.Mem.DeviceBuffer}, CuArray{Float32, 1, CUDA.Mem.DeviceBuffer}}, MaxPool{1, 2}, Conv{1, 2, typeof(relu), CuArray{Float32, 3, CUDA.Mem.DeviceBuffer}, CuArray{Float32, 1, CUDA.Mem.DeviceBuffer}}, MaxPool{1, 2}, typeof(Flux.flatten), Dense{typeof(relu), CuArray{Float32, 2, CUDA.Mem.DeviceBuffer}, CuArray{Float32, 1, CUDA.Mem.DeviceBuffer}}, Dropout{Float64, Colon, CUDA.RNG}, Dense{typeof(relu), CuArray{Float32, 2, CUDA.Mem.DeviceBuffer}, CuArray{Float32, 1, CUDA.Mem.DeviceBuffer}}, Dropout{Float64, Colon, CUDA.RNG}, Dense{typeof(relu), CuArray{Float32, 2, CUDA.Mem.DeviceBuffer}, CuArray{Float32, 1, CUDA.Mem.DeviceBuffer}}, typeof(softmax)}})(x::CuArray{Float32, 3, CUDA.Mem.DeviceBuffer})
    @ Flux ~/.julia/packages/Flux/n3cOc/src/layers/basic.jl:51
 [17] top-level scope
    @ ~/julia/test.jl:49
```

Newest CUDA version is in path, CUDNN isn't. All packages in Julia have been re-installed after the changes. Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't really a Julia problem. This error is raised when your memory isn't enough for the batch size you are trying to train at.

I suggest lowering your batch size or, in your case, the number of training data points (since you are doing it all in one batch).

Comment: Shockingly, reducing the sample size from 100k to 100 seems to have fixed it! I didn't expect to run out of memory, considering the hardware... Thanks a lot!